# Сокеты, выход за границы массива?

Tags: c#, массивы, websocket, переполнение

Люди добрые, осваиваю сокеты на c#, и увидел товарища на ютюбе, который объясняет как это делать. Вообщем, когда он принимает сообщение от клиента(простая строка) он инициализирует массива байтов с числом элементов 1024. и не узнавая размера прилетевшего сообщения, выводит его. Когда я это делал, кроме сообщения получал мусор в количестве соответствующему количеству элементов в массиве байтов. Вопрос, я то-то делаю не так, или он где то недопоказал код?
При этом, когда я присваиваю длину при получении сообщения

```
int lng = socket.Receive(data);
```

И задаю на вывод, переполнение мусором нету, выводится без лишних символов.

Comment: Это нормально. Я лично просто обернул в функцию которая чистила сообщения от пустых символов, поскольку у нас длинна сообщения не была фиксированной.

Answer (score 1):

Массив, который вы передаете в метод `Receive` - это просто выделенное место для записи в него данных. Реально там данных окажется столько, сколько удалось прочитать. Вам необходимо самостоятельно отслеживать сколько их у вас есть - это общий принцип работы с любыми потоками данных, не только с сокетами.

PS Вы зря называете вашу `lng` длиной сообщения. Потому что протокол TCP не передает сообщения, он передает сплошной поток данных! При передаче ваши сообщения могут запросто побиться на несколько или склеиться в одно.